# construct curl command in python to be placed into a python monitoring script

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, pycurl

I can issue CURL commands to an instance of my elasticsearch engine from the command line as shown below. But how can I issue these commands in python monitoring script? I can only use the default python 2.7 built-in std python packages.

Examples of commands I want to run in a python script:

delete an index:

```
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/'
```

check if index exists:

```
$ curl -XHEAD 'http://localhost:9200/twitter'


$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping' -d '
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes"}
        }
    }
}
'
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you have to use curl instead of rewriting this as urllib2 or httplib code?

Comment: yea I mean thats how i do from commandline but I can do this using some rest client. I just want a really simple script

Comment: As a different alternative: is there a reason you have to do this in Python? If all you want to do is execute commands, and you neither know nor want to learn Python, bash or Powershell or another shell will be a whole lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can generate a list of arguments as strings, you can use the subprocess module easily. For example:

```
def curl_delete(url):
    cmd = ['curl', '-XDELETE', url]
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

If you want to use the retcode as a value instead of just raising on non-zero:

```
    return subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Or if you want to get the stdout as a value, or anything else... See the subprocess docs section on replacing shell commands. Usually what you want is something like:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, _ = p.communicate()
    return out
```

However, it's worth noting that the urllib2 module can do everything in your examples (although it will be painful for some of them), and httplib can do almost anything curl can do. For example:

```
def http_delete(url):
    bits = urlparse.urlparse(bits)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(bits.host, bits.port)
    req = conn.request('delete', url)
    return req.getresponse()
```

This will return an [object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPResponse) that can give you the response code and message, headers, and body. See the [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#examples) for more details.

Comment: isnt there a way for me to simply just pass the curl command? I don't want to make a complicated script with methods etc. just a simple few lines of commands

Comment: @TazMan: the simple way to pass the curl command is the first thing I gave you. It's two lines of code--that could easily be one line of code if you didn't care about going over 80 columns. How much simpler could it be?

Comment: thank you. I'm not sure what the subprocess.call does. I certainly am only going to use the first approach because I'm not a python developer and would like to keep the script simple to start with. If you could elaborate on the first option, it would be really helpful the other options are a bit too much for me to take on. Also, the   `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, _ = p.communicate()' looks interesting. If you could also elaborate on that..  I would like to be able to capture http return codes like 200/400 etc. for successful monitoring etc.

Comment: @TazMan: "check_call doesn't work" is not a useful comment if you want help debugging your code. You have to show the code you tried and the error or incorrect result you got or nobody can help.

Comment: As for communicate, have you looked at the docs for the overview, that function, or the section on replacing other functions with subprocess? It explains better than I can. And if you have a specific question after reading that I can answer.

Comment: Actually you know what, python 2.4 is installed on the server where I am trying to write the script. So a lot of functionality is limited since its such an old version. Thats why only calls working. I want to issue a system call `os.system('<my command>')` and capture the output of that result instead of just a code such as zero. So for example lets say the command was `ls -l` I want to capture the output of the directory list in a variable of the python script. Any way for me to do that? I'll try the same with curl. Thank you!

Comment: @TazMan: You don't want to use `os.system` for almost anything. And there is no way for it to capture the output. Even Python 2.4 has `subprocess`. It doesn't have all of the functions, like `check_output`, but I just wrote an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507616/in-a-python-2-4-script-i-would-like-to-execute-a-os-system-call-ls-l-or-cur/19507725#comment28938521_19507725) explaining how to deal with that.

Comment: I don't have the PIPE command either. I will just ask the server admin to install the latest Python. Should that be fine or should I go with the all popular 2.7.5?

Comment: @TazMan: The constant `subprocess.PIPE` is there in [the 2.4 source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.4/Lib/subprocess.py#l401). You're clearly doing something wrong, but without seeing your code, I can't say what. Anyway, if you can upgrade to the latest 2.x (which is 2.7.5), that would make your life easier. (Using 3.3.2 would be even better—if you actually know Python 3.x, and are willing to do the small amount of work needed to port your existing code; otherwise, stick with 2.7.5.) But it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @TazMan: As a side note, if you can get the admin to install 2.7.5, can't you get them to configure it to allow per-user site-packages or, even better, to install `virtualenv`? Either would allow you to use many third-party packages. (Maybe not the ones that require a C compiler, but at least the pure-Python ones.)