# In a Python 2.4 script, I would like to execute a os system call `ls -l` or `curl` for example and capture the output in a variable. How to do this?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, urllib2, os.system

I am writing a python script on a remote server with an old version of python 2.4.
In the script I want to issue commands like `curl -XPUT 'http://somerul/_search' -d file.txt` or an `ls -ltrh` and capture the outputs of these commands into a variable. For the curl command the output will be a json format that I will parse (please advise if an old json parser is available for me to use)..

How can I make these kinds of system calls in the python script and capture the output into a variable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You really shouldn't ask two questions (the "system" question and the "old json parser" question) in one like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly with `os.system` or anything else in `os`. As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)* tells you, it just executes the command in a subshell. The command's stdout will be the shell's stdout which is your stdout, so there's nothing you can do to capture it.

That's why the docs explicitly tell you to use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#os.system) instead. And, if you read the docs, there's a nice section on [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module). Which includes exactly what you're trying to do as the first example.

Unfortunately, what you really want here is [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), which is unfortunately 2.7+. If you had that, it would just be:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-ltrh'])
```

---

The simplest way to get it is to install [`subprocess32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32) from PyPI, which backports everything from Python 3.2's `subprocess` module to 2.4-2.7.

If you want to stick with the stdlib, as you can see from the [2.7 source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l544), this is a trivial function to write on top of pieces that were already there in 2.4:

```
def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    if 'stdout' in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    return output
```

Or, if you just want to do this one time, you don't need the wrapper:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, _ = p.communicate()
do_something_with(out)
```

---

For your parenthetical extra question about a JSON parser:

[`simplejson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson) is the parser that became the stdlib `json` module in 2.6. The latest versions only work with 2.5+, but older versions (I believe everything before 3.0, but don't quote me on that) were for 2.4+.

---

* Note that I linked to 2.7, because 2.4 is harder to find online. But they didn't remove any features from `os.system` or `subprocess` between 2.4 and 2.7, and they do carefully note what new features were added or changed.

Comment: Wait, so i can write my own check_output command in my python script and it should work? Would there be any dependency issues? Thank you!

Comment: @TazMan: Of course you can write your own `check_output` function. You can write your own function for anything, and if you write it correctly, it will work. I suspect that isn't what you actually wanted to ask, but I can't figure out what you really _did_ want to ask…

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it in Python 2.7. I don't have the 2.4 interpreter, so I can't test it out for you:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['ls', '-ltrh']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.stdout.read()
retval = p.wait()
```

Note that for subprocess to properly work, you have to give the command as a list of arguments.

Comment: Why use an explicit `read` and wait` instead of `communicate`? It's simpler, and harder to get wrong. Also, in 2.7, surely you'd just use `check_output`, rather than doing it explicitly.

Comment: `p.communicate()` works fine, but this is more general. For example, here you could use `p.stdout.readline()` if you needed to parse output from a program as it runs.